# REST Web Service problem: /apex/FileNotFound

Tags: rest-api, rest, webservices, web

I built a REST Web service to create a custom record everytime a call is made in a calling app. Json is sent to the web service via webhook.

So far all the tests I did in sandbox were succesful and all call records were created without issues.

However, after I created the site and deployed the class to production we noticed now only some of the call records were being created.

I checked the logs and found something like this everytime a call record wasn´t created (never happened in sandbox):

```
54.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
20:46:10.0 (376721)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|005U1000000dRmj|CallApp@0000.org.force.com|(GMT+00:00) Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)|GMTZ
20:46:10.0 (467666)|EXECUTION_STARTED
20:46:10.0 (481877)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|0665f00000E6mm8|VF: /apex/FileNotFound
20:46:10.47 (47556563)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
20:46:10.47 (47556563)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

20:46:10.47 (47556563)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

20:46:10.0 (47730764)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VF: /apex/FileNotFound
20:46:10.0 (47753574)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

...While the logs of the records that were created succesfully look like this:

```
    59.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
    20:45:26.0 (299966)|PUSH_TRACE_FLAGS|[EXTERNAL]|01pU1000000A1EF|CallApp|APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
    20:45:26.0 (521349)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|005U1000000dRmj|CallApp@0000.org.force.com|(GMT+00:00) Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)|GMTZ
    20:45:26.0 (536190)|EXECUTION_STARTED
    20:45:26.0 (545040)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01pU1000000A1EF|CallApp.processRequest()
     //Class continues to execute without problems from here...
```

Am I running into some sort of Salesforce limit? Why would it only happen in production and not in sandbox?

Hope I can get some guidance from the community

Comment: This particular log is saying that whatever request came in, it didn't hit anything. Since it's likely that your site holding the web service is public, the request could come from anywhere (including attackers scanning your site) and target any valid or invalid, non-existent endpoint on your site.

Comment: @identigral Seems weird to me. that log only appears right after a call is made in the app but the record is not created.  Also it is the same user in all logs.

Comment: Public site, unauthenticated requests -> same user = site guest user.